# Chrome Invalid HTTP POST when using jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Were are facing an weird case here.

We have a page with some Hidden fields with a big amount of data (14K)  at the moment we Post the page using normal form Submittion we got an error:

> Invalid Verb

If remove jQuery we cannot reproduce this error. It looks like the Hidden fields get attached to post back action causing invalid verb.

We are using Chrome Version 53.0.2785.101 m and jQuery version 3.1.0

[image]

Comment: Could you share your jQuery code?

Comment: Fix formatting and put image inline